# Не запускается активность

Tags: android, android-appcompat

При запуске активности выскакивает ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas, PID: 9843
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas/com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class LinearView
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class LinearView
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
          at com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.LinearView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:665)
          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:65)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
          at com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.LinearView
          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
          at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 26 more
       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Ошибка возникает на строке `setContentView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

В `styles.xml` указана тема:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"></style>
```

В чем ошибка и как ее убрать?

---

UPD_0: Файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dugin_rostislav.bitsandpizzas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".OrderActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Судя по всему в манифесте у вас не та тема указана.

Comment: Прошерстите ещё все остальные папки со стилями под разные экраны, версии и всё такое. Может где-то у вас не та тема подхватывается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, о! Действительно! Была папка values-v21. Однако появилась другая ошибка. Я вопрос немного изменю :).

Comment: Менять вопросы не хорошо) А ошибка, думаю, в том, что либа какая-то не подключена. Либо надо просто имя этого класса полностью протисать (с пакетом).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если незаметно — можно :). Да и либы все подключены: и v4, и v7.

Comment: Я про LinearView вообще первый раз вижу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, упс................... :)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавляйте в ответ.

Comment: Ну... А что добавить? То что вы не ту тему в стилях для 5 андроида указали и пытались отобразить несуществующий элемент разметки?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну да).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас где-то в папке типа `values-v21` лежит `styles.xml` где вашей теме указан не тот родитель и система, беря стиль оттуда выкидывает ошибку несоответстия.

А проблема с `LinearView` - банальная опечатка. В стандартных библиотеках гугла такого элемента разметки нема.